# Cassandra issuing an error while selecting the data in table "NoHostAvailable:"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have created the keyspace and also created a table using Cassandra 3.0 server. I am using the 3 nodes architecture. And three of the servers are working and able to connect the 3 nodes. However when i insert or selecting the data using the CQL, Its showing the error saying that "**NoHostAvailable:**". Please could anyone provide me the reason and solution for this issue.

### Topology

`nodetool status` output

```
UN 172.30.1.7 230.22 KB 256 ? 2103dcd3-f09b-47da-a187-bf28b42b918e rack1 
DN 172.30.1.20 ? 256 ? 683db65d-0836-40e4-ab5b-fa0db20bae30 rack1 
DN 172.30.1.2 ? 256 ? 2b1f15d1-2f92-41ef-a03e-0e5f5f578cf4 rack1
```

### Schema

Keyspace

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2};
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE testrep(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: This is a common error you might see if your application cannot connect to the right amount of nodes in order to satisfy the consistency level required. You need to add more info to your question to get a more targeted answer though. Add `nodetool status` output to show the topology. Show your CQL commands and also show what consistency level you are using.

Comment: Here is my nodetool status 
UN  172.30.1.7   230.22 KB  256          ?       2103dcd3-f09b-47da-a187-bf28b42b918e  rack1
DN  172.30.1.20  ?          256          ?       683db65d-0836-40e4-ab5b-fa0db20bae30  rack1
DN  172.30.1.2   ?          256          ?       2b1f15d1-2f92-41ef-a03e-0e5f5f578cf4  rack1
And also I am using the SimpleStrategy with 2 copies.
CREATE KEYSPACE test  WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2};And I am creating the table using the below command.CREATE TABLE testrep(id INT PRIMARY KEY);While inserting the data getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Note that from nodetool status, 2 out of your 3 node cluster is down(DN).
You might be inserting with a Consistency Level that cannot be satisfied.

```html
nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  237.31 MiB  256          ?       3c8a8d8d-992c-4b7c-a220-6951e37870c6  rack1

cassandra@cqlsh> create KEYSPACE qqq WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 2};
cassandra@cqlsh> use qqq;
cassandra@cqlsh:qqq> CREATE TABLE testrep(id INT PRIMARY KEY);
cassandra@cqlsh:qqq> insert into testrep (id) VALUES ( 1);
cassandra@cqlsh:qqq> CONSISTENCY 
Current consistency level is ONE.
cassandra@cqlsh:qqq> CONSISTENCY TWO ;
Consistency level set to TWO.
cassandra@cqlsh:qqq> insert into testrep (id) VALUES (2);
NoHostAvailable: 
cassandra@cqlsh:qqq> exit
```

Comment: cqlsh:hptest> CONSISTENCY
Current consistency level is ONE.
cqlsh:hptest>


I have checked the Cassandra status in each of the node. it is showing the each node is up in Localhost. However, Other nodes are in Down status. Please help me how can I configure two achive the replication and the issue which I am getting (NoHostAvailable).